# Secure password storage for a launchd daemon

Tags: cocoa

In a normal Cocoa application it's typical to store any saved passwords in the Keychain and thus avoid many pitfalls.  Now I'm writing a launchd daemon that needs to store a password and will run before any user has logged in.  This means I cannot use the keychain like I normally do.

I see in Keychain Access there is a "system" keychain, but I have been unable to find any documentation whatsoever on how to use it (or if this is the correct use for it).

What is the best practice for storing passwords used by launchd daemons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own Keychains and use them willy-nilly. For example, you could have one inside your app bundle, if you have an app bundle.

Or you could run the daemon as a particular user (the guy who installed it) and put the key in his keychain, then just reach into his home folder when you need it.

Or you could run the daemon as root and put your key in the System keychain.

-Wil

Comment: Any idea where the System keychain is documented? I was unable to find out how to put something in the System keychain.

Comment: You can use the open keychain function (don't know it offhand) and just pass in the path to the system keychain. Done and done.

Comment: This works.  I used SecKeychainOpen("/Library/Keychains/System.keychain") from my daemon running as root.  The big caveat is that you MUST use code signing or any code change will make it impossible to read your stored password(s).

Comment: So by virtue of the fact that the process is running *as* a certain user, it automatically has access to that user's keychain?  That sounds... like a possible security hole.

Comment: It is, but this is mitigated by users being able to set policies on each Keychain. Eg: unlocked at login vs. requiring a password to unlock, and timeouts to re-lock the keychain automatically. Plus individual items can require passwords every time, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

keychains are tightly tied to the concept of User context. therefore if you need a background process that deals with a user's keychain, then you should be using the UserAgent model.
because deamons are typically (if not always) root:wheel priveleged, a typical scenario where a daemon would require some kind of credentials would be covered by kerberos (file sharing on a web server, XGrid agents, things like this). by no means should a root:wheel daemon be using the credentials of a user.

Comment: It specifically does not care at all about users, but it still needs to store a credential.  In this case, a secret API passcode for a remote web service.  The process needs to have this credential even when you're at the login screen, before any user has signed in.

Comment: if you have a look in /private/etc you will find that many of the daemons running on your machine refer to .conf files in that folder. however on a read-only basis AFAIK. maybe you can have your installer place a .conf file there and MD5 your creds into it or so...